# How to make my recently used command appear on the top of vscode autocomplete

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am wondering is there any way to make my most recently used command appear on the top of the autocomplete suggestions in vscode for GO.

For example, I type `fmt.printf()` and next time when I type `fmt.` , it will put `.printf()` as the first choice of the autocomplete suggestions. As my observation, the suggestion is always in the fixed order, it won't change with my operations. So I am wondering is there any way to set up it?

Comment: Have you tried changing `editor.suggestSelection`?

Answer (score 0):

After checking [vscode-go issues](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/search?q=most%20recent%20completion&type=issues), and its code, I don't see anything which would enable that feature.

The completion menu order does not seem to be configurable (for now).